# Is there any online source of Flurry documentation/info?

Tags: flurry

I've been asked to add Flurry to an iPhone application, and I'm finding that the Flurry.com site doesn't appear to have any online documentation to speak of.

Is there any good source of info on Flurry use/features/behaviors anywhere, by Flurry or 3rd parties?  (Or, rather, am I forced to ask each new question here?)

Answer (score 4):

I've found a modest documentation page [here](http://support.flurry.com/index.php?title=Main_Page). But it was not easy to find. Flurry is a great tool, but they really should improve their documentation.

Answer (score 2):

Once you register on flurry.com and create an application: your dashboard -> Applications -> "Add new application" or click this [link](https://dev.flurry.com/createProjectSelectPlatform.do). Once application is created follow this [download](https://dev.flurry.com/uploadVersionSelectProject.do) link.

**EDIT:** myself I already have applications created in Flurry and don't remember if having an app was a precondition to download, so maybe try downloading SDK directly by clicking 2nd link.

**EDIT2:** if your looking just for a demo or features summary, check out their "Products" subpage, e.g. [Analytics](http://www.flurry.com/product/analytics/index.html).

Comment: That doesn't get you any real documentation, so far as I can tell, other than a dozen or so lines on how to install Flurry in your app.

Comment: Inside the zip file you should find: Analytics-README.pdf, AppCircle-README.pdf and RELEASE_NOTES.txt plus library itself and some other files. The first PDF should be sufficient - it served me well. But please write what kind of documentation you expect?

Comment: That's pretty much the same documentation that was on the download page.  I would like, for instance (only a small instance) a description of what logPageView is supposed to do -- what page does it log, and how does it identify it??  Also info on how quickly data from an app turns up on the Flurry site.  Is is necessary to specify AppStore ID to get Flurry to work?  Many others.

Comment: (Declaring an app is a prereq for the download, though of course it can be a dummy name.)